# How should Create Next App Offline be used?

Tags: next.js, module, create-react-app, offline

According to the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app#why-use-create-next-app), using Create Next App has the benefit of **Offline Support**:

> Create Next App will automatically detect if you're offline and bootstrap your project using your local package cache.

If I turn off wifi and try `npx create-next-app` or `pnpm create next-app`, I'll get errors even if I've previously ran the commands *while* connected to wifi (thus presumably creating a local package cache).

How is this supposed to be used?

Comment: did you find out how this works? I'm looking into offline support for my Next.js app too, and I can't find any additional info anywhere about that line in the doc.

Comment: I haven't. However I haven't kept investigating either.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that in the docs as well. For all of Next's aggressive caching strategies, it seems to force clear all caches as soon as the user goes offline. Even using a tool like next-pwa doesn't even work, Next overrides my service worker no matter what which is pretty terrible. It doesn't seem that Next has any intention of adding this kind of functionality.

I think the only solution is to get out of the Next ecosystem if you want a offline first strategy. Personally, I would switch to Remix.run if I had the option. There is a package @remix-pwa that seems to actually work to solve the issues. The Remix team is actually working with the developer. https://dev.to/shafspecs/remix-pwa-v30-a-new-era-48f

Also, it seems like all of Next's real innovation is coming from copying stuff Remix did. But in all fairness I haven't had much of a chance to use Remix as much as I have wanted to, so take this all with a grain of salt.